# What kind of functionality differences are there in jsp and standalone java applications?

Tags: java, jsp

Or APIs accessible by standalone java applications also accessible by jsp?

Comment: JSP's are converted to Java classes, which are compiled.  A JSP **is** Java.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Everything you can do in a standalone Java application, you can do in a JSP. However, this isn't the recommended way of doing things. It is better to keep Java code in servlets or beans and have only the presentation layers in JSPs. Using [taglibs](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as JSP is compiled into a servlet you can access all the regular APIs. However, be aware that servlets are each run in a separate thread. Only use thread safe APIs in JSP pages.